# python - Return if a row is the lowest value in a column for the last n rows except for the most recent rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe:

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsrm5.png)

I want to create a new column called 'is_new_low' which contains a boolean value and returns True if:

- The associated rows 'close' value is less than the smallest 'low' value of the last 2000 rows, **but ignoring the last 20 rows**.

Ie, if the current 'close' is greater than the 'low' from 5 (or any number =< 20) rows ago, but is less than all 'low' values from the last 1980 rows starting the count at the current index -20, still return True.

Else return False.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv("eurusd.csv", names =['time','open', 'high', 'low','close'])

df.loc[df['close'] < df['low'].rolling(2000).min(), 'is_new_low'] = True
df.loc[df['close'] > df['low'].rolling(2000).min(), 'is_new_low'] = False
df.loc[df['close'] == df['low'].rolling(2000).min(), 'is_new_low'] = False
```

But this just returns false in every row because I cant figure out how to ignore the last 20 rows and a rows 'low' will never be greater than a rows 'close'.

Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Share data in text format and not in image format. Just copy the data and paste it here. It is more useful in text format

Answer (score 0):

You can take a 2000 window-size rolling approach you've taken, slicing each window up to the last 20 elements before taking the min:

```py
df['is_new_low'] = df['close'] < df.rolling(2000)['low'].apply(lambda x: x[:-20].min())
```